# Summarize dataframe by grouping on a column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

i have a dataframe

```
id  store  val1    val2
1    abc    20      30
1    abc    20      40
1    qwe    78      45
2    dfd    34      45
2    sad    43      45
```

from this i have to group by on `id` and create a new df, with column, `total_store` and `unique stores` and `non-repeating_stores`, which contains count of such store occurances.
my final output should be

```
id    total_store    unique stores    non-repeating_stores
1        3              2                   1
2        2              2                   2
```

i can get total stores by doing

```
df.groupby('id')['store'].count()
```

But how do i get others and form a dataframe out of it

Comment: @Zero Sorry i edited it now

Comment: @SRingne - I add timings to my answer, please check it.

Comment: @jezrael wow! such drastic difference by using drop_duplicates!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `groupby` + `agg`.

```
df = df.groupby('id').store.agg(['count', 'nunique', \
                lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(keep=False).size])
df.columns = ['total_store', 'unique stores', 'non-repeating_stores']

df    
    total_store  unique stores  non-repeating_stores
id                                                  
1             3              2                     1
2             2              2                     2
```

---

For older pandas versions, passing a dict allows simplifying your code (deprecated in `0.20` and onwards):

```
agg_funcs = {'total_stores' : 'count', 'unique_stores' : 'nunique', 
         'non-repeating_stores' : lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(keep=False).size
}
df = df.groupby('id').store.agg(agg_funcs)

df 
    total_stores  non-repeating_stores  unique_stores
id                                                   
1              3                     1              2
2              2                     2              2
```

---

As a slight improvement with speed, you can employ the use of `drop_duplicates`' sister method, `duplicated`, in this fashion, [as documented by jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46465090/4909087):

```
lambda x: (~x.duplicated(keep=False)).sum()
```

This would replace the third function in `agg`, with a 20% speed boost over large data of size `1000000`:

```
1 loop, best of 3: 7.31 s per loop
```

v/s

```
1 loop, best of 3: 5.19 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) and [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html). Last function is a bit complicated - need count all non dupes using inverting [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `sum`:

If need count `NaN`s use `size` instead `count`:

```
df = df.groupby('id')['store'].agg(['count', 
                                   'nunique', 
                                    lambda x: (~x.duplicated(keep=False)).sum()])
df.columns = ['total_store', 'unique stores', 'non-repeating_stores']
print (df)
    total_store  unique stores  non-repeating_stores
id                                                  
1             3              2                     1
2             2              2                     2
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000


L = np.random.randint(10000,size=N).astype(str)
df = pd.DataFrame({'store': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'id': np.random.randint(10000, size=N)})
print (df)

In [120]: %timeit (df.groupby('id')['store'].agg(['count',  'nunique', lambda x: (~x.duplicated(keep=False)).sum()]))
1 loop, best of 3: 4.47 s per loop

In [122]: %timeit (df.groupby('id').store.agg(['count', 'nunique', lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(keep=False).size]))
1 loop, best of 3: 11 s per loop
```

Comment: I dont undestnad, sorry.

Comment: Hmm... I don't get such drastic timings on my machine. For me, it's more like, `1 loop, best of 3: 5.19 s per loop` vs `1 loop, best of 3: 7.31 s per loop`. How does it do for small data?

Comment: Because windows? I dont know.